# Updating Attributes in AD Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script updating attributes in AD.  Attached is a sample of my script to update the attributes. This does work but I am not a PowerShell guy by any means. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to run my script.
Some issues I am having is if a field in the CSV is blank it generates an error, and if there is blank field on csv file it does not replace existing data in the attribute.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\sdk\employees to update.csv"

#####Udating givenName
foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "FAKEcompanyEmployeeNumber -eq '$($user.EMPLOYEE)'" -Properties givenName -SearchBase "OU=Staff Win10,dc=FAKEcompany,dc=on,dc=ca" | 
    Set-ADUser -replace @{"givenName" = "$($user.Emp_First_Name)" }
}

#####Udating sn
foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "FAKEcompanyEmployeeNumber -eq '$($user.EMPLOYEE)'" -Properties sn -SearchBase "OU=Staff Win10,dc=FAKEcompany,dc=on,dc=ca" | 
    Set-ADUser -replace @{"sn" = "$($user.Emp_Last_Name)" }
}

#####Udating FAKEcompanyEmployeeNumber
foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "FAKEcompanyEmployeeNumber -eq '$($user.EMPLOYEE)'" -Properties FAKEcompanyEmployeeNumber -SearchBase "OU=Staff Win10,dc=FAKEcompany,dc=on,dc=ca" | 
    Set-ADUser -replace @{"FAKEcompanyEmployeeNumber" = "$($user.Employee)" }
}

#####Udating middleName
foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "FAKEcompanyEmployeeNumber -eq '$($user.EMPLOYEE)'" -Properties middleName -SearchBase "OU=Staff Win10,dc=FAKEcompany,dc=on,dc=ca" | 
    Set-ADUser -replace @{"middleName" = "$($user.Middle_Name)" }
}
```

Comment: You can do multiple replacements in one call of `Set-ADUser` like in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-3-set-properties)

Answer (score 0):

```
#The where filter on $_.[propertyname] filters objects out where the specified properties are empty 
$users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\sdk\employees to update.csv" | ?{$_.employee -and $_.Emp_First_Name -and $_.Middle_Name}

#As Santiago mentioned you can do it in one step
foreach ($user in $users){
    Get-ADUser -Filter "FAKEcompanyEmployeeNumber -eq '$($user.EMPLOYEE)'" -Properties givenName -SearchBase "OU=Staff Win10,dc=FAKEcompany,dc=on,dc=ca" | set-aduser -replace @{givenName=$user.Emp_First_Name;sn=$user.Emp_Last_Name;FAKEcompanyEmployeeNumber=$user.Employee;middleName=$user.Middle_Name}
}

#################

#If you want to process also objects with partital information you can do
$users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\sdk\employees to update.csv"
foreach ($user in $users){
    $Replace = @{}
    If ($user.Emp_First_Name){
        $replace.add('givenName',$user.Emp_First_Name)
    }
    If ($user.Emp_Last_Name){
        $replace.add('sn',$user.Emp_Last_Name)
    }
    If ($user.Employee){
        $replace.add('FAKEcompanyEmployeeNumber',$user.Employee)
    }
    If ($user.middle_name){
        $replace.add('middleName',$user.middle_name)
    }
    Get-ADUser -Filter "FAKEcompanyEmployeeNumber -eq '$($user.EMPLOYEE)'" -Properties givenName -SearchBase "OU=Staff Win10,dc=FAKEcompany,dc=on,dc=ca" | set-aduser -replace $replace
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I was taken away from this to work on other items. I will see if i can get this to work for me.

Comment: If the field is blank or empty on the csv file is there a way to overwrite a populated field in AD with the blank field from the csv file?

Comment: y... use the first example and remove the filter ```| ?{$_.employee -and $_.Emp_First_Name -and $_.Middle_Name}```

Answer (score 0):

You can set multiple replacement values for user attributes as shown in the [`Set-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-3-set-properties) documentation in [**Example 3**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-3-set-properties).

[`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-7.0) can help you check if the value for the column is empty in your Csv.

Hopefully the inline comments can help you understand the logic.

```bash
$properties = @{
    givenName  = 'Emp_First_Name'
    sn         = 'Emp_Last_Name'
    middleName = 'Middle_Name'
    FAKEcompanyEmployeeNumber = 'Employee'
}

Import-Csv -Path "C:\sdk\employees to update.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $params = @{
        Filter     = "FAKEcompanyEmployeeNumber -eq '{0}'" -f $_.EMPLOYEE
        SearchBase = 'OU=Staff Win10,dc=FAKEcompany,dc=on,dc=ca'
    }
    # if we can find the user in AD,
    # check which properties need to be updated for this user
    if($adUser = Get-ADUser @params) {
        # replace hashtable for splatting latter
        $replace = @{ Replace = @{} }
        foreach($property in $properties.GetEnumerator()) {
            $value = $_.($property.Value)
            # if this Value is empty in the Csv
            if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($value)) {
                # skip it, go next
                continue
            }
            # here we assume the Value in the CSV is populated,
            # add it to the replacement hash
            $replace['Replace'][$property.Key] = $value
        }

        # check one last time if the replacement hash is populated
        if($replace.Values.Keys.Count) {
            # if it is, we can go ahead and set values for the AD User
            $adUser | Set-ADUser @replace
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Disregard my last statement, I got it working. Thank you

Comment: If the field is blank or empty on the csv file is there a way to overwrite a populated field in AD with the blank field from the csv file?